# How can I properly use Laravel5 form features?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, laravel-5

I am a ZendFramework fan. My past three years was with ZF2. I am now trying to move to Laravel5. I love the Zend Framework form creation and validation using the `\Zend\Form` class. It is easy to define the form by extending the Zend form class and just dump in view. After posting the form `$form->isValid()` makes life more easier.

I am digging through the Laravel5 documentation. I can see form related things are handled by `Request` class. I don't find a proper alternative to Zend form. I am afraid I am missing some golden part from Laravel documentation.

How should I correctly use the form in Laravel5?

Comment: you could try this link for some details on form with Laravel5 http://slashnode.com/mastering-form-validation-laravel-5/

Comment: @fSazy, Thanks, but it only shows the form validation.

Comment: I'm new to Laravel myself, but from what I understand the built-in class for building forms' HTML has been removed from Laravel 5. You can check https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/10 (also episode 12 is for the validation).

Answer (score 0):

The built in class has indeed been removed from Laravel 5, so you need to add it back in. A discussion that shows you exactly what to do is covered over here.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-forms